# Reading specific time format and subtracting from it

Tags: ruby

I am working on a problem I found on the internet:

> The human body goes through 90 minute sleep cycles during the night, and you feel more refreshed if you wake up at the end of a sleep cycle than if you wake up during a sleep cycle. The challenge is to make a program that takes a wake-up time and outputs the possible times to fall asleep so that you will wake up at the end of a sleep cycle.*

My approach to this problem is to subtract 90m from the time five times after parsing it to `DateTime` and storing it into an array. However, I'm new to Rails and am not quite sure how to do this. How do I display my time in the original format?

Here is what I have so far:

```
require 'date'

def sleep_time time
  a = []

  5.times do |i|
    multiple = i * 90 * 60
    a << time - multiple
  end

  puts a
end

puts "Enter wake-up time: "
time = DateTime.strptime(gets, '%I:%M %p').to_time

puts time
sleep_time(time)
```

Edit: I figured out how to subtract 90m (using seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time supports `strftime`, which takes a format string that is consistent with `strptime`. Use:

```
time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

For instance:

```
Time.now.strftime('%I:%M %p')
=> "01:29 PM"
```

Also, don't parse it into a DateTime object then convert to a Time object using `to_time`. Instead parse directly into a Time object. Time supports `strptime` also:

```
require 'time'
Time.strptime('01:29 PM', '%I:%M %p')
=> 2012-09-20 13:29:00 -0700
```

---

If you want to parse from a given format, then output in that format again, define a constant and use it in the `strptime` and `strftime` methods:

```
TIME_FORMAT = '%I:%M %p'
Time.strptime('01:29 PM', TIME_FORMAT)
time.strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ActiveSupport Extensions you can work with `1.day + 90.minutes - 10.seconds`. You find that [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html).

```
# ActiveSupport Extensions will us allow to use 90.minutes
require 'active_support/all'

def go_to_sleep_at(end_time, sleep_cycles = 5)
  # Parse input into time object
  end_time = Time.parse(end_time)
  # Add one day
  end_time += 1.day if end_time.past?

  # Calculate start times
  start_times = []
  (1..sleep_cycles).each {|i| start_times << end_time - (90.minutes * i)}

  # Define output format
  time_format = '%H:%M %p'

  # Format times
  end_time = end_time.strftime(time_format)
  start_times.map!{|t| t.strftime(time_format)}.reverse!

  # Return output
  return "If you want to wake up at #{ end_time } you can go to sleep at #{start_times[0..-2].join(', ')} or #{start_times.last}."
end

p go_to_sleep_at('06:00')
# => "If you want to wake up at 06:00 AM you can go to sleep at 22:30 PM, 00:00 AM, 01:30 AM, 03:00 AM or 04:30 AM."
```

Just one of myriads of solutions :-D